# Converting a textfile to a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, text, helper

My file:

[image]

**Goal:** to read a txt file and return dictionaries

What I have:

```
def load_snacks(snack_file: TextIO) -> Tuple[Dict[str, List[str]],
                                              Dict[str, List[str]]]:
    """Return a two-item tuple containing a "healthysnack_to_junkfood" dictionary
    and a "healthysnack_to_healthysnack" dictionary with the data from snack_file.
    """
    snack_H2J = {}
    snack_H2H = {}

    line = snack_file.readline().strip()

    while line != '':
    # due to structure of the file, line contains a healthy snack name

        healthysnack_name = line

    # properly format the 1st healthy snack name, use helper fcn (see below for helper fcn)

        flip_name_and_del_comma(healthysnack_name)  

        healthy_list = []
        junk_list = []        

        line = snack_file.readline().strip()
        while line != '\n':
            if ',' in line:
                snack_H2J[healthysnack_name] = line
                a = flip_name_and_del_comma(line) 
                healthy_list.append(a)

            else:
                snack_H2H[healthysnack_name] = line
                junk_list.append(line)

    line = snack_file.readline().strip()

    return (snack_H2J, snack_H2H)
```

Below is my helperfcn; I have verified that this works

```
def flip_name_and_del_comma(s: str) -> str:
    """ Retrun a new str that reverses the format name order from 'colour, healthy snack name' to 
    'healthy snack name to colour'

    >>> flip_name_and_del_comma('orange, carrot')
    'carrot orange'
    >>> flip_name_and_del_comma('yellow, mango')
    'mango yellow'
    """
    s_reversed = ', '.join(reversed(s.split(', ')))

    s_comma_delete = s_reversed.replace(', ', ' ')

    return s_comma_delete
```

Comment: What is your problem precisely? Is it throwing any errors?

Comment: hi, I want to read the text file and return contents as a dictionary

Comment: Like {"orange":"carrot","red":"apple" ... } ? What about chocolate that does not have a word after?

Comment: Or it is lemon chocolate in the same line?

Comment: Hi an example of the two dicts would be: Junk dict is following: {'carrot orange': ['chips'], 'lemon yellow': [chocolate]}

Comment: example of helathy dictionary is the following: {'carrot orange': ['kale green', 'apple red'], 'lemon yellow': ['plum purple'], 'blueberries blue': [], 'blackberries black': ['mango yellow']}

Comment: The problem is not very intuitive, how are we suppose to know wich one are healthy and which one are junk food?